# Can DCL be rolled back in transactions?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can DCL commands (e.g. GRANT/REVOKE) be committed/rolled back as transactions in snowflake? I can't find any mention of how DCL is handled in the snowflake transaction documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Explicit transaction](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html#explicit-transactions):

> Explicit transactions should contain only DML statements and query statements. **DDL statements implicitly commit active transactions (for details, see the DDL section).**

GRANT and REVOKE are also considered
[User & Security **DDL**](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/ddl-user-security.html):

> Access Control Management
>
> Use the following commands to manage access control for objects by granting (and revoking) object privileges to roles and granting roles to users and other roles:
>
> - GRANT  … TO ROLE
> - REVOKE  … FROM ROLE

Answer (score 0):

DCL commands always force a commit(implicit autocommit if they are successfully executed without errors) and will in turn commit all statements before them.